# How to use devtools::use_data on a list of data frames?

Tags: r, devtools

I have a series of data frames that I want to save as individual .rda files in my package.

I could use `devtools::use_data(my.df1, my.df2...)` but I don't have a named object for each data frame, they are all stored in a big list.

What I would like is to do is to call use_data for each list element and use the list name for the .rda file name.  But when I do the following, I have an error message:

```
> lapply(my.list, devtools::use_data, overwrite = TRUE)
Error: Can only save existing named objects
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `use_data` function seems to be very odd indeed requiring that an unquoted name is passed as a parameter that points to the object you want to save. This isn't conducive to working with objects in lists. But here is a possible solution with `walk2` from `purrr` (though you could probably we-write with an `mapply()` if you want to use just base R)

```
library(purrr)
library(devtools)

walk2(my.list, names(my.list), function(obj, name) {
  assign(name, obj)
  do.call("use_data", list(as.name(name), overwrite = TRUE))
})
```

Comment: last line should be `do.call("use_data", list(as.name(name), overwrite = TRUE))`

Comment: Why does this (i.e., calling through `do.call`) work when simply writing `use_data(as.name(name), overwrite=TRUE)` fails?  I'd have thought the two would be functionally identical.

Comment: In order for `as.name(name)` to return a name, you have to evaluate it. `use_data` does not evaluate its first parameter, it looks for a variable literally named “as.name(name)”.

Comment: I wonder if this is possible if the object exists in a function environment only.

Answer (score 1):

You loop Assign(my.list, newNameOfYourList) over your list of lists.
Then use devtools::use_data(newNameOfYourList, overwrite = TRUE).