# How to dynamically change names inside a for loop in usethis::use_data() R

Tags: r, rstudio

This is my first time creating an R package. I am trying to include 39 different datasets into the pre-loaded data for my package. However the usethis::use_data() function which creates the .rda files takes an unquoted name only and not a variable. Therefore
data = dynamic_name_from_for_loop

it keeps creating a file data.rda instead of dynamic_name_from_for_loop.rda

```
library(usethis)
library(readtext)
library(tidyverse)

site_list = c('0034L','0081L','0089L','0166L','0220R','0236L','0307R',
              '0333L','0414R','0434L','0445L','0450L','0476R','0501R','0515L',
              '0566R','0629R','0651R','0688R','0701R','0817L','0846R','0876L',
              '0917R','0938L','1044R','1194R','1227R','1233L','1377L','1396R',
              '1459L','1726L','1833R','1946L','2023R','2133L','2201R','2255R')


for (i in 1:length(site_list)){
  sitename = site_list[i]
  filename = paste0('M:/Tools/GCsandbar/data-raw/',sitename,"sd.csv")
  data = read.csv(filename, header = T)
  df_name = paste0('RC',sitename,'sd')
  assign(df_name,data)
  usethis::use_data(data,name = df_name, overwrite = TRUE)
  #file.rename(from = 'data/data.rda',to = paste('data/',df_name,'.rda')) ## this did not work
}
```

This just creates 39 instances of df_name.rda overwriting the previous one each time, instead of creating RC0034L.rda, RC0081L.rda, ....

Answer (score 5):

`use_data` asks for unquoted names of the objects to be saved. 
There is no argument called `name`, in the function, and as far as I can see, `name = df-name` is doing nothing.
Try `do.call` instead.

```
library(usethis)
library(readtext)
library(tidyverse)

site_list = c('0034L','0081L','0089L','0166L','0220R','0236L','0307R',
          '0333L','0414R','0434L','0445L','0450L','0476R','0501R','0515L',
          '0566R','0629R','0651R','0688R','0701R','0817L','0846R','0876L',
          '0917R','0938L','1044R','1194R','1227R','1233L','1377L','1396R',
          '1459L','1726L','1833R','1946L','2023R','2133L','2201R','2255R')


for (i in 1:length(site_list)){
  sitename = site_list[i]
  filename = paste0('M:/Tools/GCsandbar/data-raw/',sitename,"sd.csv")
  data = read.csv(filename, header = T)
  df_name = paste0('RC',sitename,'sd')
  assign(df_name, data)
  do.call("use_data", list(as.name(df_name), overwrite = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: This question and answer look similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673667/how-to-use-devtoolsuse-data-on-a-list-of-data-frames

Answer (score 1):

In the loop, the `use_data` can be changed to `use_data_raw`

```
usethis::use_data_raw(df_name)
```